# How would I disable/hide context menu of axShockwaveFlash?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, flash, axshockwaveflash

I currently have a project in which I am using axShockwaveFlash to play my .swf file.

Is there a way I can disable the context menu that appears when I right click on this?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29102/How-To-Disable-FlashPlayer-AxShockwaveFlash-Right ?

Comment: Hmm, sadly this is quite old and I'm not quite sure how to implement it. This source project also no longer works on modern machines. Do you know how I could implement this into my project?

Comment: Sorry, have never used this old and retired thing. I thought that link could lead you to somewhere.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working eventually but with some modifications. Thank you!

Comment: @BlakeXavier Why not share the answer? It might help others with same problem.